# Nonlinear PDE $u_y=(u_x)^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to show that the only solutions of $u_y=(u_x)^3$ that are smooth on whole $\Bbb R^2$ are of the form $ax+by+c$, could anyone help me please?

Comment: I got a solution of $$u=\frac{2i}{\sqrt{27}}\frac{x^\frac{3}{2}}{y^\frac{1}{2}}$$ but that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Hi again @MohammadrezaBidar, consider accepting the answer in order to mark the question as closed. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

The [***Lagrange-Charpit equations***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) tell us that:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x }{3p^2}  = \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{-1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u }{3p^3-q} = -\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{0} = -\frac{\mathrm{d} q}{0}.$$

Thus, from the last two fractions we can conclude that:

$$ p = A, \quad q = B, \quad A,B \in \mathbb{R}. $$

If you separately integrate both equations$^1$, since $p = \partial_x u$ and $q = \partial_y u$, you will get to:

\begin{align}
u & = A x + \mu(y) \\
u & = B y + \eta(x)
\end{align}

where $\mu$ and $\eta$ are some functions of their arguments. Looking at this set of conditions we can conclude that necesarily $\eta(x) = Ax$ and $\mu(y) = B$ and hence:

> $$ \color{blue}{u(x,y) = A x+ By}$$

It's up to you now to show that any function of the form $\tilde{u} = u(x,y)+k$ is also a solution, where $k$ is a constant.

Cheers!

---

$^1$: Of course you can take advantage of the fact:

$$ \mathrm{d}u = p \, \mathrm{d}x + q \, \mathrm{d}y,$$

which is integrable since $p$ and $q$ are constants. Your result immediately follows.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It is an easy and helpful way :)

Comment: Glad to help @MohammadrezaBidar!