# How do address non-linear but still first order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have an equation $u_y - u_x^3 =0$, but because it's non-linear in a broader $F(x,y,z,p,q)$ case with $u_x=p, u_y=q$, I can't rely on the typical characteristic equations in the simpler linear case. But as far as I can tell, there is some kind of comparable technique I can use, but what exactly?

Comment: Separation of variables maybe works?!

Comment: Look at the [Lagrange-Charpit equations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&ved=2ahUKEwjFhMT4x_fnAhVSvZ4KHcOUCzsQFjARegQICRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu%2F~mate%2Fmisc%2Fcharpits_method_compl_int.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2i3EDXsz33FYyNavPK6fTg). A similar question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903659/nonlinear-pde-u-y-u-x3).

Comment: In the LC equations, what is "s"? Is it actually supposed to be $t$ as in the other characteristic equations? Or is it supposed to be $s$ for arclength?

Comment: I was expecting $$\frac{dz}{dt} = p\frac{dx}{dt} + q\frac{dy}{dt},$$ but maybe that is the wrong equation.

Comment: How did they get $\frac{dx}{3p^2}$? I mean it looks like $F_p$ but how did they know how to do that? The characteristic looking equations in the book I'm reading are more complicated than that.